# select an element in a python list without comma-separated

Tags: python, opencv, numpy-ndarray

I have a list like this:

```
[[437   5  91  91]
 [331 303 155 155]]
```

How can I choose the first or second element in this list?
The output I want:

```
[437   5  91  91]
```

i have two face in my camera in face detection then i have this list in my output:

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(PATH) 
.... 
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale( gray, 
                                       scaleFactor=1.2, 
                                       minNeighbors=10, 
                                       minSize=(self.face_size, self.face_size) 
                                      )
```

when i print(faces) i have this output and i want to select one of this elements.

```
type(faces) gives `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` this is type of faces
```

Comment: That is not a valid python list. That is a syntax-error.

Comment: You mean a string that looks like a list right?

Comment: Are you perhaps saying that is a string and you want to convert it to a list?

Comment: when i print(faces) i have this output and i want to select one of this elements

Comment: This is not a valid list in vanilla python. You may want to update your question with the other libraries you're using, and the code you have that generated the 'list' to begin with. It's likely a different object type that has different syntax to access. Have you tried `type(list)`?

Comment: @MackRty: Please [edit] your Question instead of commenting. Delete moved comments!

Comment: @MackRty then it is not `list`. If I had to guess, it's a `numpy.ndarray` object

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**:  i want to select one of this elements.

Read about [Common Sequence Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)

---

> [docs.opencv.org](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cv2.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale)
>   **Python: cv2.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale2**(image[, scaleFactor[, minNeighbors[, flags[, minSize[, maxSize]]]]]) → objects, numDetections
>
> Detects objects of different sizes in the input image.
>   The detected objects are returned as a list of rectangles.

This call return **two** objects, you can split it, for example:

```
objects, numDetections =  cv2.CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale2(...
```

or

```
objects, numDetections =  faces
```

or

```
objects = faces[0]
numDetections =  faces[1]
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you mean a strinh instead of list you can do the following

```
import json

test="[[437   5  91  91] [331 303 155 155]]"

#convert the multiple whitespace to single white space
test=' '.join(test.split())

#replace whitespace with comma
test=test.replace(" ",",")

#make a list of it
lists = json.loads(test)

print(lists[0])
```